# filebeat to elk with regex

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have logs with the following config :

```
/var/log/app_id/machine_id.log
```

I would like to stream the logs into ELK with filebeat that would have the fields message, date etc, but also app_id and machine_id as a field. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried looking up different processors but no luck so far

Comment: There's no processor for what you want to do out of the box. The easiest way to do it only with filebeat is to write a simple JS script and use the [Script Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html). Just `event.Get(source)`, extract the substrings and enrich the messages with `event.Put(app_id, value)`.